# Custom TableView and Header

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, tableview

I have a single Custom TableView with a Header cell. The problem is that I am only able to display one set of data and the TableView will not currently scroll (Maybe because of only one set of data being displayed.) This is in Swift 3.

Here is my Code:

ViewController:

```js
  

  

struct TableData {

        var section: String = ""
        
        var data = Array<String>()
        
        var dataS = Array<String>()
        
        init(){}

    }

    var data = Array<TableData>()
    var dataS = Array<TableData>()

    class MyCustomCell: UITableViewCell {

        @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!
        
        @IBOutlet var labelS: UILabel!
        
    }

    class MyCustomHeader: UITableViewCell {

        @IBOutlet var header: UILabel!
        
    }

    class TypeViewController: BaseViewController , UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
        
        @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
        
        @IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!

        public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
            return data[section].data.count
        
        }
        
        public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! MyCustomCell
            
            cell.label.text = data[indexPath.section].data[indexPath.row]
            cell.labelS.text = dataS[indexPath.section].data[indexPath.row]
            
            return cell

           
        }
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
            
            let  headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Header") as! MyCustomHeader
            
            headerCell.header.text = data[section].section
            
            return headerCell

        }
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
            return 50.0
        }
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        print(indexPath.row)
        
        var element: TableData
        
        element = TableData()
        
        element.data.append(data[indexPath.section].data[indexPath.row]);
        
        wordData.append(element)
        
        element = TableData()
        
        element.data.append(dataS[indexPath.section].dataS[indexPath.row]);
        
        wordDataS.append(element)
        
        if wordData[indexPath.section].data.count == 3 {
            
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueFind", sender: self)
            
        }
        
    }
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            addSlideMenuButton()
            addItems()
            
            print(data)
            
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }
        
func addItems() {

        var new_elements:TableData

        new_elements = TableData()
        new_elements.section = "Gevurah - Judgement"
        new_elements.data.append(obj1);
        new_elements.data.append(obj2);
        new_elements.data.append(obj3);
        new_elements.data.append(obj4);
        new_elements.data.append(obj5);
        new_elements.data.append(obj6);
        new_elements.data.append(obj7);
        
        data.append(new_elements)
        
        new_elements = TableData()
        new_elements.section = "Hod - Reverberation"
        new_elements.data.append(obj11);
        new_elements.data.append(obj12);
        new_elements.data.append(obj13);
        new_elements.data.append(obj14);
        new_elements.data.append(obj15);
        new_elements.data.append(obj16);
        new_elements.data.append(obj17);
        
        data.append(new_elements)
        
        new_elements = TableData()
        new_elements.section = "Tiferet - Beauty"
        new_elements.data.append(obj21);
        new_elements.data.append(obj22);
        new_elements.data.append(obj23);
        new_elements.data.append(obj24);
        new_elements.data.append(obj25);
        new_elements.data.append(obj26);
        new_elements.data.append(obj27);
        
        data.append(new_elements)

 new_elements = TableData()
        new_elements.section = "Gevurah - Judgement"
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS1);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS2);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS3);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS4);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS5);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS6);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS7);
        
        dataS.append(new_elements)
        
        new_elements = TableData()
        new_elements.section = "Hod - Reverberation"
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS11);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS12);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS13);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS14);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS15);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS16);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS17);
        
        dataS.append(new_elements)
        
        new_elements = TableData()
        new_elements.section = "Tiferet - Beauty"
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS21);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS22);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS23);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS24);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS25);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS26);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS27);
      
        dataS.append(new_elements)

}
```

Also, I am getting an index out of range error on this line:

`element.data.append(dataS[indexPath.section].dataS[indexPath.row]);`

Attached are some Photos of the MainStoryboard:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yvw7I.png

i.stack.imgur.com/nLWZJ.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ralOb.png

Comment: add screenshot for your output screen .

Comment: Ok, I will try to do that tomorrow, basically One Section Header is Displayed with 7 Rows with text beneath it

Comment: ok . is displayed another section ?

Comment: No, just one section header and its rows are displayed. But I think anupam's answer might solve the issue

Comment: One more problem I was having was in the didSelectRowAtPath. I can't add the value from DataS to WordData

Answer (score 0):

Put some code for number of section in your class it will definitely work.

```
public func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
{
    return dummyArray.count
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer Anupam. I will try this tomorrow and comment if it works